# define height of element against width of parent div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I set the height of an element based on the width of it's parent div ?

if I do

```
height: <some_ratio>vw
```

I'm getting a height that equals `some_ratio` of the viewport's width.
I want `some_ratio` of parent div's width.
Is that possible ?

(I need this to generate square elements in bootstrap cols. Thus the height of those elements must equal the width of the col)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pure CSS way, you can set the children height to 0 and then use padding-bottom to set a percentage :) (paddings are based on width, even the top/bottom padding)

```css
.parent{
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
}
.child{
    background: blue;
    width: 50px;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
</div>
</div>
```